# Forcing output in Esper

Tags: esper

I have a non real time Esper configuration where I feed a stream that I read from a file. I'm trying to create an expression that computes a statistic over the entire stream and outputs one value at the very end. Esper has semantics for forcing a view to output every X seconds, for instance, but is there a semantic for asking the view or the engine to "flush" the output  when you know there are no more events to feed.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out that at least one way to do this is to use the output clause with a variable trigger.

The expression would be:

```
select count(*) as totalCount from events output last when OutputSummary = true
```

The OutputSummary variable would be initialized like so:

```
epConfiguration.addVariable("OutputSummary", Boolean.class, "false");
```

When you're ready to flush, set the variable to true like so:

```
epRuntime.setVariableValue("OutputSummary", true);
long currentTime = epService.getEPRuntime().getCurrentTime();
epRuntime.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(currentTime));
```

It's necessary to send another time event to force the expression to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

When output requires at every 60 sec then the expression would be:

```
select emplyee_id from employees output snapshot every 60 sec
```

and when the output requires at every 10000 events then the expression would be:

```
select emplyee_id from employees output snapshot every 10000 events
```